# mysql #1312 - PROCEDURE can't return a result set

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [use result set of mysql stored procedure in another stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466713/use-result-set-of-mysql-stored-procedure-in-another-stored-procedure)

Executing Mysql stored procedure in phpMyadmin getting error

my stored procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE `SP_GetNews`//
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_GetNews`()
BEGIN

(Select * from tbl_news where Nw_Dontshowstatus = 0) order by Nw_UploadedTime desc;

END
```

when calling the SP

```
CALL SP_GetNews;
```

will giving the error:

> mysql #1312 - PROCEDURE  can't return a result set in the given context

Any solution?