# mysql Calling a stored procedure inside another stored procedure returns result of the inner call

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've been trying to, in a stored procedure, call another stored procedure and do stuff to the result of it. I've read [use result set of mysql stored procedure in another stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466713/use-result-set-of-mysql-stored-procedure-in-another-stored-procedure) and notice that I need to, in the inner call, create a temporary table to store the result and consult that temporary table in the outer call.

However, whenever I call the outer stored procedure, it always return the result of the inner stored procedure call.

To simplify this I make two stored procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `classmates`.`three` () 
 NOT DETERMINISTIC 
begin
SELECT 3;
end;
```

and:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `classmates`.`four` () 
 NOT DETERMINISTIC 
begin
call three();
SELECT 4;
end;
```

then I call:

```
call four();
```

it returns:

```
+-------------+
| 3           |
+-------------+
| 3           |
+-------------+
```

Why does it not return 4?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: changing the procedures to DETERMINISTIC doesn't help. Also my real 'three()' procedure is a pretty long procedure and not deterministic, and the result contains > 10 columns. Copying the code from 'three()' to 'four()'... well that definitely works, but reduces code reuse.

PS this is the first time I ask a question, so sorry if I am not making myself clear and please let me know!

EDIT: RESOLVED, thanks to Barmar!

I made a helper stored procedure that only creates temporary tables and does not do any SELECT statements alone. Then in both procedure calls I call this helper. Problem solved!

Comment: A procedure returns the result set from its first `SELECT` statement. Try `begin select 3; select 4; end` and you'll see the same thing. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/211da/1

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was the last select statement. Does something like CREATE TABLE tablename SELECT ... also count?

Comment: OK they do not count. Thank you so much Barmar!

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` doesn't return anything. Only `SELECT` returns a result.

Comment: Cool. I'll fiddle around more. Thank you!