# How to select some columns of a stored procedure in Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, ranking

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `RankAll`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    select userID,sum(score) as score,@rank := @rank + 1 AS rank  from
    (
        select userID,score from ScoreMessages  
        union all   
        select userID,score from ScoreExams
    ) as scores
    JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) rank
    group by userID
    order by score desc;
END
```

Actually I wanted to use it as a view but I have variables because I wanted to rank them and it did not let me to use it in a view.

I tried the query below but it is not correct:

```
select * from (Call `RankAll`())
```

So how can I select multiple columns out of it?

Comment: I think you have to make the stored procedure save its results in a temporary table. Then you can select from that table. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466713/use-result-set-of-mysql-stored-procedure-in-another-stored-procedure for a similar problem.

Comment: It's not possible to use the resultset(s) returned from a procedure within another SQL statement. The procedure cannot be referenced as row source for a query. If you were using SQL Server, you could write a table valued function. The closest you are going to get in MySQL is to have the procedure populate a temporary table, and then reference the temporary table in a separate query. With the example shown here, the query in the procedure could be taken out of the procedure, and used as an inline view definition. (Replace the `Call RankAll` with the query. And assign a table alias of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use the resultset(s) returned from a procedure within another SQL statement. A procedure cannot be referenced as row source within a query.

If we were using SQL Server, you could write a table valued function. But we can't do that in MySQL. The closest we get in MySQL is having a procedure populate a temporary table, and then reference the temporary table in a separate query.

With the example shown here, the query could be taken out of the procedure, and be used as an inline view definition. That is, replace the `Call RankAll()` with the actual query. And assign a table alias of course.

```
SELECT v.userid
     , v.score
     , v.rank
  FROM ( -- inline view
         SELECT s.userid
              , SUM(s.score) AS score
              , @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank
           FROM ( SELECT m.userid
                       , m.score
                    FROM ScoreMessages m  
                   UNION ALL
                  SELECT e.userid
                       , e.score
                    FROM ScoreExams e
                ) s
          CROSS
           JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) i
          GROUP BY s.userid
          ORDER BY s.score DESC
       ) v
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
call RankAll()
```

The call returs the result set as if you would run the same SQL query.

Comment: So how can I select multiple columns out of it?

Comment: MySQL does not have concept of table valued function. What you need to do is to store the results to a temporary table and use that in the calling procedure / application.

Comment: MySQL temporary tables are visible to the process, whereas in SQL Server temporary tables are visible inside the procedure you create them. In MySQL you can create a temporary table, call the procedure to populate it and then use the result set after the call.

So:
drop temporary table if exists data_tmp;
create temporary table data_tmp (id int, score int,  rank int);
call RankAll();  /* populate the data_tmp */
select * from data_tmp;